# php array merge not giving expected/desired results

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

With the following code I am able to generate 2 arrays..

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');

    //ignores first line of csv
    fgetcsv($file_handle);


    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}

// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'csv1.csv';
$csvFile2 = 'csv2.csv'; 
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
$csv2 = readCSV($csvFile2);

echo '<pre>';
$arr = [];
//$csv is your array
foreach($csv as $key => $value){
  if(!array_key_exists($value[24],$arr)){
    $arr[$value[24]] = [];
  }
  $arr[$value[24]] = array_merge($arr[$value[24]],$value);  
}
//ignores last item in array
array_pop($arr);

$arr2 = [];
//$csv2 is your array
foreach($csv2 as $key => $value){
  if(!array_key_exists($value[1],$arr2)){
    $arr2[$value[1]] = [];
  }
  $arr2[$value[1]] = array_merge($arr2[$value[1]],$value);  
}

echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($arr);
print_r($arr2);
echo '</pre>';
```

This outputs the arrays as follows..
Array 1 ($arr)

```
Array
(
    [1593608448] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03/25/20
            [1] => Vinyl Decal Sticker
            [2] => 
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2.85
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0.00
            [8] => 0.00
            [9] => 2.49
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 2.85
            [12] => GBP
            [13] => 1829006957
            [14] => 627718667
            [15] => 03/25/2020
            [16] => 03/25/2020
            [17] => John Smith
            [18] => Any Street
            [19] => 
            [20] => Somewhere
            [21] => Someplace
            [22] => PC0 DE
            [23] => United Kingdom
            [24] => 1593608448
            [25] => Colour:Yellow
            [26] => online
            [27] => listing
            [28] => online_cc
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 0
        )

)
```

And array 2 ($arr2)

```
Array
(
    [1593608448] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03/25/20
            [1] => 1593608448
            [2] => 
            [3] => John Smith
            [4] => John
            [5] => Smith
            [6] => 1
            [7] => Credit Card
            [8] => 03/25/20
            [9] => Any Street
            [10] => 
            [11] => Somewhere
            [12] => Someplace
            [13] => PC 0DE
            [14] => United Kingdom
            [15] => GBP
            [16] => 2.85
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 0.00
            [20] => 0.00
            [21] => 2.49
            [22] => 0
            [23] => 5.88
            [24] => 
            [25] => 0.44
            [26] => 4.9
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => John Smith
            [31] => online
            [32] => online_cc
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
        )

)
```

I have attempted to merge these arrays with..

```
$merged = array_merge($arr,$arr2);
print_r($merged);
```

This outputs as..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03/25/20
            [1] => Vinyl Decal Sticker
            [2] => 
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2.85
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0.00
            [8] => 0.00
            [9] => 2.49
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 2.85
            [12] => GBP
            [13] => 1829006957
            [14] => 627718667
            [15] => 03/25/2020
            [16] => 03/25/2020
            [17] => John Smith
            [18] => Any Street
            [19] => 
            [20] => Somewhere
            [21] => Someplace
            [22] => PC0 DE
            [23] => United Kingdom
            [24] => 1593608448
            [25] => Colour:Yellow
            [26] => online
            [27] => listing
            [28] => online_cc
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03/25/20
            [1] => 1593608448
            [2] => 
            [3] => John Smith
            [4] => John
            [5] => Smith
            [6] => 1
            [7] => Credit Card
            [8] => 03/25/20
            [9] => Any Street
            [10] => 
            [11] => Somewhere
            [12] => Someplace
            [13] => PC 0DE
            [14] => United Kingdom
            [15] => GBP
            [16] => 2.85
            [17] => 
            [18] => 
            [19] => 0.00
            [20] => 0.00
            [21] => 2.49
            [22] => 0
            [23] => 5.88
            [24] => 
            [25] => 0.44
            [26] => 4.9
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => John Smith
            [31] => online
            [32] => online_cc
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
        )

)
```

When I wanted/expected..

```
Array
(
    [1593608448] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03/25/20
            [1] => Vinyl Decal Sticker
            [2] => 
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2.85
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0.00
            [8] => 0.00
            [9] => 2.49
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 2.85
            [12] => GBP
            [13] => 1829006957
            [14] => 627718667
            [15] => 03/25/2020
            [16] => 03/25/2020
            [17] => John Smith
            [18] => Any Street
            [19] => 
            [20] => Somewhere
            [21] => Someplace
            [22] => PC0 DE
            [23] => United Kingdom
            [24] => 1593608448
            [25] => Colour:Yellow
            [26] => online
            [27] => listing
            [28] => online_cc
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 0
            [32] => 03/25/20
            [33] => 1593608448
            [34] => 
            [35] => John Smith
            [36] => John
            [37] => Smith
            [38] => 1
            [39] => Credit Card
            [40] => 03/25/20
            [41] => Any Street
            [42] => 
            [43] => Somewhere
            [44] => Someplace
            [45] => PC 0DE
            [46] => United Kingdom
            [47] => GBP
            [48] => 2.85
            [49] => 
            [50] => 
            [51] => 0.00
            [52] => 0.00
            [53] => 2.49
            [54] => 0
            [55] => 5.88
            [56] => 
            [57] => 0.44
            [58] => 4.9
            [59] => 
            [60] => 
            [61] => 
            [62] => John Smith
            [63] => online
            [64] => online_cc
            [65] => 
            [66] => 
        )

)
```

So keeping the order id (which is always [24] in 1 arr1 and [2] in the arr2) as the key then add on to the end of the matching key in $arr1 the contents of the matching key from $arr2 with the numbers just following on.

I have looked at many similar questions and answers on here but not getting the results I require.
Or another way of putting it is it will check if [24] and [2] match and then append on to the end

Comment: For any future questions, please try to produce a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. Your point could have been illustrated with sample arrays with no more than 2 or 3 values.

Comment: @El_Vanja noted.

Comment: `array_merge` is not what you're looking for, if you read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge) properly. Looks like you'll need to write a custom function using a loop.

Comment: Is your end result the 2 arrays or just the 1 merged array?

Comment: Im thinking it would be similar to the one used previ. something like foreach($csv, $csv2 as $key => $value){
  if(!array_key_exists($value[1],$arr2)){
    $arr2[$value[1]] = [];
  }
  $arr2[$value[1]] = array_merge($arr2[$value[1]],$value);  
} but i really am clueless what to change.

Comment: @NigelRen final result will be 1 merged array for each same key from my prev function result that turns the order id into the key i believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to merge the data as you read it.  I was going to change your read so that it read the CSV as it created the arrays, but I have left the `readCSV()` as it is - except to add `array_filter()` to remove empty elements.

Rather than create the two arrays and then merge them, I've change the second CSV loop to check `$arr` and add the data at this point...

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');

    //ignores first line of csv
    fgetcsv($file_handle);


    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);

    $line_of_text = array_filter($line_of_text);
    return $line_of_text;
}

$csvFile = 'csv1.csv';
$csvFile2 = 'csv2.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
$csv2 = readCSV($csvFile2);

echo '<pre>';
$arr = [];
//$csv is your array
foreach($csv as $key => $value){
    if(!array_key_exists($value[24],$arr)){
        $arr[$value[24]] = [];
    }
    $arr[$value[24]] = array_merge($arr[$value[24]],$value);
}

foreach($csv2 as $key => $value){
    if(!array_key_exists($value[1],$arr)){
        $arr[$value[1]] = [];
    }
    $arr[$value[1]] = array_merge($arr[$value[1]],$value);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thank you, not only achieved exactly what I needed and took a much better approach to boot. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge_recursive` instead of `array_merge`

```
$merged = array_merge_recursive($arr,$arr2);
```

Comment: I have just tried this and its the same undesired result, still the order id (keys) are not copied over and still it's not one continually numbered array but instead it wraps a new array around the both but keeps the numbering as the old ones.